# Highcharts - Bubble chart - Moving gridlines

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, bubble-chart

I have created a highcharts bubble chart as follows:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/svcuLgso/)

If possible I'd like the a-axis gridlines to be in the middle of the bubbles.

Is there a way of achieving this ?

Here's the code:

```
$(function () {

    var data = [{ x: 0, y: 1, z: 1, dataSeries: 'data #1', dataPerc: '1.2' },
                { x: 1, y: 2, z: 2, dataSeries: 'data #2', dataPerc: '2.2' },
                { x: 2, y: 0, z: 0, dataSeries: 'data #3', dataPerc: '19.2' },
                { x: 3, y: 7, z: 7, dataSeries: 'data #4', dataPerc: '12.0' },
                { x: 4, y: 5, z: 5, dataSeries: 'data #5', dataPerc: '24' },
                { x: 5, y: 4, z: 4, dataSeries: 'data #6', dataPerc: '12' },
                { x: 6, y: 3, z: 3, dataSeries: 'data #7', dataPerc: '15.3' },
                { x: 7, y: 3, z: 3, dataSeries: 'data #8', dataPerc: '1.2' }];         

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
            credits: false,

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
           categories: ['data #1', 'data #2', 'data #3', 'data #4', 'data #5', 'data #6', 'data#7', 'data #8']
        },

        yAxis: {
            startOnTick: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            title: {
                text: 'Score'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            },
            maxPadding: 0.2
        },

        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            headerFormat: '<table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.dataSeries}</h3></th></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Score:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Percentage:</th><td>{point.dataPerc}%</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            followPointer: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{ data: data }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`tickmarkPlacement` option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement):

```
xAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
}
```

> For categorized axes only. If `on` the tick mark is placed in the center of the category, if `between` the tick mark is placed between categories. The default is `between` if the `tickInterval` is 1, else `on`. Defaults to `null`.

See [this updates JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svcuLgso/6/) for an example.

Comment: Cracking - Thanks :)